# how can get last 10 record from table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have controller that have function to get my post from table like this:-

```
function getPosts($user_id, $from, $to) {
    $this->db->order_by("ev_date", "DESC");
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->table_name, array('ev_user_id'=>$user_id));

    return $query->result();
}
```

above function i can get all post from table but i need only display last 10 record from tabel.

the second problem the table " post " has user_id whos add this post, and store user_id, and when get all post i need 
to get the user name from " user " table.

the table user match with the post table by "User_id"

Comment: i wont to replace this active to CI `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users,events WHERE users.id = events.ev_user_id and ev_user_id = '".$user_id."' order by ev_date DESC limit 10");`

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you need a join to get the user name,  a join with codeigniter active record works like this:

```
$this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = post.user_id');
```

you can use limit to limit your query

```
$this->db->limit(10);
```

source:
[CodeIgniter user manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: i wont to replace this active to CI `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users,events WHERE users.id = events.ev_user_id and ev_user_id = '".$user_id."' order by ev_date DESC limit 10");`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPosts($user_id, $from, $to) {
    $this->db->order_by("ev_date", "DESC");
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->table_name, array('ev_user_id'=>$user_id), 10, 0);

    return $query->result();
}
```

From the CI docs.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

Comment: i wont to replace this active to CI `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users,events WHERE users.id = events.ev_user_id and ev_user_id = '".$user_id."' order by ev_date DESC limit 10");`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function tenData()
{
    $query = $this->db
            ->order_by('id' , 'desc')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get('yourTable');

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

You can try this. order_by your id and add limit.

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers because people with low knowledge of the topic might have trouble using them for learning purposes. Try to add an explanation of what is done in this answer :-)